# All PHP files getting hacked

Tags: php, security, malware

Like always, just want to say thank you for all of the help and input in advance.

I have a particular site that I am the web developer for and am running into a unique problem. It seems that somehow something is getting into every single PHP file on my site and adding some malware code. I have deleted the code from every page multiple times and changed FTP and DB passwords, but to no avail.

The code that is added looks like this - eval(base64_decode(string)) - which the *string* is 3024 characters.

Not sure if anyone else has ran into this problem or if any one has ideas on how I can secure my php code up.

Thanks again.

Comment: Is this custom code? Or is it WordPress or something similar?

Comment: This is custom and does not have any CMS built in.

Comment: To sum up all the answers below: Please POST MORE DETAILS. It can be bad PHP or server config problems or other users on the same machine... just almost everything. Edit the question and write more.

Comment: @naugtur - I don't know what else to say...I have posted what I know. A piece of code is being inserted onto every PHP file on my server. The code uses the base64_decode function nested inside the eval function with a string inside of it. Not sure what else I could post. I am on a shared hosting server and have switched my ftp passwords. I guess I need some guide as to what else I should have in my post?

Comment: What does `base64_decode(string)` return?

Comment: If it's malware, the decoded string is probably a lot of javascript. But I suppose it can't hurt for him to look...

Comment: This question has been asked to death.

Comment: @pygorex1: most likely a malicious php payload. @BlueRaja: lol

Comment: You need to provide: server info - where it is, what it is, who has access; Your app info - does it manipulate files - write stuff depending on user provided variables;

Comment: Look for a copy of FCKEditor.  If you have it DELETE IT.

Comment: If you're on a unix server, check your file system write permissions. 'Other' shouldn't need to have it. Then contact the server admin and report the problem. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_permissions#Traditional_Unix_permissions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server itself could be compromised. Report the problem to your web host. What is their response?

An insecure PHP script coupled with incorrect file permissions could give the attacker the ability to modify your PHP files. To eliminate this possibility I would take the site down, delete all the files, re-upload, then switch permissions on the entire site to deny any writes to the file system.

**Edit:**
As a short-term fix try asking your web host to disable `eval()` for your account. If they're worth their salt they should be running [Suhosin](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/) which has an [option to disable eval](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/configuration.html#suhosin.executor.disable_eval).

Comment: As a conclusion - I did follow up with the hosting company and they were not much help (go figure). Interesting enough this died down after a couple weeks and just recently surfaced. Some of my team members were able to find the problem. It was an outdated version of AWStats. We made sure to request they update AWStats to the most recent version server wide and have not had any problems since. Hope this helps anyone!

Answer (score 2):

You should use "disable_functions=eval,exec" in your php.ini or .htaccess as first measure.

Answer (score 1):

yes i have ran into this problem myself, i take it you are on a shared host? are you perchance on rackspacecloud?

this is where i had that problem, the first thing you need to do right away is notify your host, this is a hosting issue, and i suspect the malware has gained access to your server on an ftp level.

make sure you have nothing chmod 777 world writable, if it needs to be writable by your app make it 775

hope this helps, good luck

Comment: I am on shared host, but not on rackspacecloud. I have notified my hosting solution and they are saying it is a PHP security problem.

Comment: @nsearle, can you get more information than "It is a PHP security problem"? What do they mean by that?

Comment: @Marcus Adams - That is a great great question. I was just told that it could be some random PHP security problem and that "I" needed to tighten up my problem. GD fails again.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the file permissions so that only you can write to those files. 0777 (the default on some hosts, I believe) is just asking for trouble. [See File Permissions.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_permissions)

Also, it's advisable to not put any files that aren't supposed to be accessible by URL outside of the public_html folder, for example, config files.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. However, my problem was that I was running a python code evaluator on my site. As far as I remember you need to use eval() function to execute the python code. In one of my php files I had a weird eval statement. What kind of script are you developing? I mean does it involve evaluation of some other code?

Answer (score 1):

You should also note that (assuming you are using a hosting solution to host your site) that it's almost never your fault. An example being that networksolutions hosting company recently had a server hacked and over 1K webpages were affected, not due to security holes on each particular site, but due to some bad configuration/monitering of what was put on that particular server that hosts those sites. If you can't see any thing security wise wrong with your code, aka you sanitize everything properly and or you are running a non vulnerable version of whatever CMS you are using (if your using a CMS) then it's probably not an issue with your site, just the server in general.

Answer (score 0):

You should move to another server. It would appear that the attacker has access to the server or is running some code as a background process which is overwriting the files. It may be possible to identify and remove the problem, but smart attackers will hide additional scripts etc to trip you up later.

Comment: That makes sense. Sadly, I do not have control over the hosting company, at this moment. I even talked to them on support and they are saying it's a PHP security hole.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible scenarios is that somebody managed to get write access somehow and changing passwords etc. helped, but he left a php file that can still run.

See if there are any unknown files there. Or delete every damn thing and restore some backups.

Answer (score 0):

Get the last modified time of your files, then go over to your access logs (FTP, HTTP whatever's open, if you don't know where they are ask your host) and find out who was mucking around on your system at that time.

Likely the attacker has installed a script that they can call periodically to re-infect any files you fix.